# Menu2 under menu1 in scanner: how to order all cases?

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

3 questions:

1. Input `Menu2` under `Menu1` in scanner: how to order all possible cases including exceptions?
2. How to separate menu values and shape values in scanner: while / if or some other way?
3. Why printCalc() function is not working when call it under if?

import java.util.*;

public class ScannerShape {

```
public static void printCalc() {
    ArrayList<Shape> list = new ArrayList <Shape> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i)+"Area: "+list.get(i).calcArea()+" Circumference: "+list.get(i).calcCircumference());
    }
}
public static void printMenu1() {
    System.out.println( "1. Add new shape\r\n" + 
            "2. List all shapes\r\n" +
            "3. Sum all circumferences\r\n" +
            "4. Sum all areas\r\n" +
            "5. Find biggest circumference\r\n" +
            "6. Find biggest area\n" +
            "7. Exit" +
            "Enter a number from the list above");
}
public static void printMenu2() {
    System.out.println( "1. Square\r\n" + 
            "2. Rectangle\r\n" + 
            "3. Circle\r\n" + 
            "4. Right triangle\r\n" + 
            "Enter a number from the list above");
}
public static void main (String[] args) {       
    int i = 0; 
    int val, val1 = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    printMenu1();
    while (true) {          
        val=sc.nextInt();
        if (val == 7) {
            System.out.println("Exit");
            break;                           
        }                     
        if (val == 1)
            printMenu2();
        val=sc.nextInt();   

        if (val == 1)
            System.out.println("Enter Square width");
        val=sc.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Shape> list = new ArrayList <Shape> ();
        list.add(new Square(val));
        printCalc();

        if (val == 2) {
            System.out.println("Enter Rectangle height");
            val=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Rectangle width");
            val=sc.nextInt();
            val1=sc.nextInt();
            list.add(new Rectangle(val,val1));
            printCalc();
        }
        if (val == 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter Circle radius");
            val=sc.nextInt();
            list.add(new Circle(val));
            printCalc();
        }

        if (val == 4) {
            System.out.println("Enter Right triangle height");
            val=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Right triangle width");
            val1=sc.nextInt();
            list.add(new Triangle(val,val1));
            printCalc();
        }
        if (val1 == 2) {
            System.out.println("2. List all shapes");
            printCalc();
            val1=sc.nextInt();
        }   
        if (val1 == 3) {
            System.out.println("3. Sum all circumferences");

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < list.size(); i1++) {
                for (int i2 = 0; i2 < list.size(); i2++) {
                    list.get(i1).calcCircumference();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(list.get(i)+" Circumference: "+ list.get(i).calcCircumference());    
            val1=sc.nextInt();
        }   
        if (val1 == 4) {
            System.out.println("4. Sum all areas");
            val1=sc.nextInt();
        }
        if (val1 == 5) {
            System.out.println("5. Find biggest circumference");
            val1=sc.nextInt();
        }   
        if (val1 == 6) {
            System.out.println("6. Find biggest area");
            val1=sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: its kind of a duff's device( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device )  I would recommend against such thing.  But try to use switch instead of the if as that may guide you to improve the structur. (I am saying this looking at your code and finding it difficult to give a usefull answer to the first question without major refactoring) Most important: Can you please post something reproducible?

Comment: what's the expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Thank you, Kai and Hari. I will try switch. Input- should be tested each case: so wrong cases of char or empty enter. Possible int for menu1 and double for menu2. Output - double.

Comment: Input- all shapes sizes (possible enter and save same shape several times). Output - double of first menu answers from 2 to 6 (possible collect all answers) and calculate sum areas or sum circumferences for all shapes before Exit.

Answer (score 0):

This version is working:

import java.util.*;

public class ShapesScanner {

```
public static void main (String[] args) {       
    boolean shouldExit = false;

    while (!shouldExit) {
        printMainMenu(); 
        int menuSelection = sc.nextInt();

        if (shapes.size() == 0 && menuSelection != 1) {
            System.out.println("Error: Shape or parameter was not selected or selected no one;");           
            continue;
        }
        switch (menuSelection) {
        case 1:
            printAddShapeMenu();
            addShape(sc.nextInt());
            break;

        case 2: {                   
            for (Shape sh : shapes) {  
                sh.toString();              // Print List of all entered Shapes;
            }
        } break;

        case 3: {
            double sum = 0;
            for (Shape sh : shapes) {
                sum += sh.calcCircumference(); 
            }
            System.out.println("Sum all circumferences: "+ sum + "\n");
        } break;

        case 4: {
            double sum = 0;
            for (Shape sh : shapes) {
                sum += sh.calcArea();
            }               
            System.out.println("Sum all areas: "+ sum + "\n");
        } break;

        case 5: {               
            double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Shape sh : shapes) {
                double num = sh.calcCircumference();
                min = Math.min(min, num);
                max = Math.max(max, num);
            } 
            System.out.println("Biggest circumference: " + max + "\n");
            System.out.println("Min circumference: " + min + "\n");
        } break;    

        case 6: {               
            double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Shape sh : shapes) {
                Double num = sh.calcArea();
                min = Math.min(min, num);
                max = Math.max(max, num);
            } 
            System.out.println("Biggest area: " + max + "\n");
            System.out.println("Min area: " + min + "\n");
        } break;

        case 7: {
            System.out.println("Exit");
            shouldExit = true;
        }
        break;
        }
    }
}
// printMainMenu(), printAddShapeMenu(), addShape(int shapeNum) - print menus, add Shapes, enter the Shape parameters and save;  
private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
private static ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();    // Save all entered Shapes;

public static void printMainMenu() {
    System.out.println( "\n1. Add new shape\n" + 
            "2. List all shapes\n" +
            "3. Sum all circumferences\n" +
            "4. Sum all areas\n" +
            "5. Find biggest circumference\n" +
            "6. Find biggest area\n" +
            "7. Exit" + "\nEnter a number from the list above\n");
}
public static void printAddShapeMenu() {
    System.out.println( "\n1. Square\n" + 
            "2. Rectangle\n" + 
            "3. Circle\n" + 
            "4. Right triangle\n" + 
            "Enter a number from the list above\n");
}
public static void addShape(int shapeNum) { 

    switch (shapeNum) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println("Enter width");
        double width = sc.nextDouble();
        shapes.add(new Square(width));                              // Save all Square parameters;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        System.out.println("Enter width and height");
        double width = sc.nextDouble();
        double height = sc.nextDouble();
        shapes.add(new Rectangle(height,width));                    // Save all Rectangle parameters;
        break;  
    }
    case 3: {
        System.out.println("Enter radius");
        double radius = sc.nextDouble();
        shapes.add(new Circle(radius));                             // Save all Circle parameters;
        break;
    }
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Enter width and height");
        double width = sc.nextDouble();
        double height = sc.nextDouble();
        shapes.add(new Triangle(width, height));                    // Save all Triangle parameters;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid shape specified");
    }
}
```

}